# ¿Cuándo adquirió la segunda N la palabra «cansancio»?

Tags: historia

He notado que en uno de los libros que ahora leo, la costumbre es escribir la palabra *cansancio* sin la segunda **n**, es decir como *cansacio*.

Hoy, la única forma aceptada es *cansancio*, pero no tuvo que cambiar.  El portugués y gallego mantienen la palabra sin la consonante nasal como *cansaço*<sub>(pt)</sub> y *cansazo*<sub>(gl)</sub>.<sup>1</sup>

¿Cuándo apareció la forma *cansancio*? Si siempre convivía con la forma *cansacio*, ¿cuándo desapareció ese último?

---

<sup>1. El asturiano también tiene la segunda **n**, pero no podemos aprovechar con una comparación respecto al aragonés o catalán por usar estos sufijos diferentes, *cansera*<sub>(ar)</sub> y *cansament*<sub>(cat)</sub>.</sup>

Comment: ¿De qué año es el libro que lees? ¿Está escrito por un autor español o hispanoamericano?

Comment: @fedorqui es de 1493, así que adivina de qué lado ;-)

Comment: Ya decía yo que no estarías leyendo algo de este siglo ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revisando el NTLLE veo que desde 1495 en los diccionarios aparece *cansancio*, con la segunda *n*. Nebrija lo traduce como *defatigatio* y Covarrubias en 1611 lo define como "la fatiga del cuerpo". Solo un diccionario, el Bluteau de 1721, recoge *cansacio*. Curiosamente, es un diccionario de español-portugúes por lo que puede que se usara el término *cansacio* por influencia de este idioma, dado que [el autor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Bluteau) vivió dos tercios de su vida en Portugal.

Por otro lado, si buscamos en el CORDE vemos que hasta 1600 hay 559 casos de *cansancio* en 210 documentos, mientras que tan solo hay 37 casos de *cansacio* en 17 documentos. Hacia este siglo pues la palabra *cansancio* ya estaba asentada, pero si nos vamos un poco más atrás, restringiendo la búsqueda hasta el 1500 aparecen 41 casos y 17 casos, respectivamente. Restringiendo hasta el 1400 aparecen 11 casos y 9 casos. Y restringiendo hasta el 1300 aparecen 4 y 7 casos, que es cuando la tendencia se invierte y aparecen más casos de *cansacio*.

Por tanto, la versión con dos *n* debió hacerse más popular hacia el siglo XV, como se demuestra teniendo en cuenta que en 1495 ya aparecía así en los dicionarios.

Answer (score 4):

Es posible que el origen del castellano *cansancio* y del portugués *cansaço* no sea el mismo.

No existe ningún otro sustantivo derivado de verbo que utilice el sufijo *-ncio* para expresar un estado o acción, como *cansancio* a partir de *cansar*. El sufijo habitual es el femenino *-ncia* (como en *vagancia, potencia*, etc.), que proviene directamente del latín *-ntia*. En *cansancio*, y sólo en ella, ese sufijo cambia inexplicablemente de género.

Por otro lado el *cansaço* portugués utiliza un sufijo diferente. No conozco tanto portugués pero creo que este uso también es único, o bien se desprende figurativamente del uso de *-aço* como marca de golpe o movimiento violento (correspondiente a nuestro *-azo*): *cansaço* sería un "golpe de fatiga", un cansarse repentino y violento.

Hay otras palabras portuguesas que terminan en *-ço* pero éste corresponde al español *-cio* (del latín *-tium*), como en *preço* (esp. *precio* < lat. *pretium*), o bien resultan de una raíz verbal terminada en /s/ que proviene de una sibilante palatal (y que en español tendrá generalmente una *-z-*), como en *abraço*.

¿De dónde proviene la vacilación entre *cansacio* y *cansancio*? Quizá la primera forma, más antigua y cercana a la norma iberorromance, no sonaba del todo bien a algún oído y fue influenciada por la gran cantidad de sustantivos derivados con *-ncia*. Quizá esta influencia bastó para que la nasal se introdujera en la palabra, pero no tanto como para hacerla cambiar de género.

Comment: Ambas respuestas son excelentes, pero tuve que escoger una y los datos de CORDE me ha hecho preferir mínimamente la respuesta de @Charlie .